# How do I parse time in another locale to US locale?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have a time picker that a user can change, and I need to take the time that they selected and convert it back into US format. I am currently trying to use the DateFormatter so I can easily convert it from one date format to another that I can easily work with.

Here is the code that I am been trying to use, but it does not work:

```
let time = "上午11:42"  //11:42 AM
let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") 
timeFormatter.timeStyle = .short
timeFormatter.dateStyle = .none
timeFormatter.isLenient = true
timeFormatter.date(from: time)  //returns nil
```

The time format should be pretty dynamic since a user can change their language to anything supported by the iOS device.

Comment: You have to use the language the user has used, that's all to it.

Comment: You mean set the Locale to `Locale(identifier: "zh-Hans_US")`?

Comment: Yes. However it's not common to parse date entered by user as a string. Usually users enter dates using a picker.

Comment: @Sulthan Setting the Locale seemed to work (don't know why I didn't try that before), thanks!

But yes, they are picking a date from a picker and not manually entering one in.

Comment: If they are entering the date using a picker, then the picker already gives you the date.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, the parser has to use the locale that was used to generate that string.

However, parsing localized strings is an antipattern. If the users enter dates using a picker, you should use the date from that picker. You shouldn't format it to a string and than parse it back.

That introduces a lot of complexity (including timezones, daylight saving time changes etc).

Comment: The reason I convert it to a date, is because I need to format that date into a different format and submit it to our API. So I was trying to come up with a solution that parses a date/time that a user selects back into a format that is standardized and the format the API is expecting.

Comment: @ConnorChappell The API should not use localized formats, they should use some specific format, usually the ISO format, that can be generated/parsed always in the same way. Again, localization should be done only to present data to the user in UI, not to store the data in localized form in a database. Localized data becomes unusable once the user changes language.

Comment: Maybe I am not phrasing my problem correctly (also still pretty new to software development). I get a date and time from our API in ISO format, but I am displaying it in a different way (Long style). I then have to parse the date/time that is in a different format (that they can change to a different date/time) back into the ISO format

Comment: @ConnorChappell I am pretty sure the problem can be solved just by keeping the `Date` instance in a variable instead of parsing it from the localized format.